# Right-click on the dataGridView options to change its default fields

Tags: c#, winforms

Right click on the dataGridView options to change its relevant fields using contextMenuStrip

I added a contextMenuStrip to the form and changed the contextMenuStrip dataGridView1 to the same contextMenuStrip that I had created.
The problem is that I want every field to be right-clicked and the name option is clicked to display the name of that field dataGridView1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.